# Asking multiple questions in single slot in RASA

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have got a question, I have an api that gives a json list of questions, the questions may be of type 'text' or 'MCQ', now I want to utter those questions to user and the user will answer them one by one. The number of questions may vary depending on API response, it may be from 2 to 10, text and choice based. How can I come over this issue ?